# Is it possible to duplicate a specific slide using google slide api?

Tags: node.js, google-slides-api, google-slides

Google Slides Api (Node JS / JavaScript) - is it possible to create a duplicate of a specific slide like for example assuming slide no 5 needs to be duplicated 3 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to copy the specific slide in Google Slides several times.

  - In your question, you want to copy No. 5 slide 3 times.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for Node.js.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Slides using Slides API.

In this case, I thought that the method of batchUpdate in Slides API can be used.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, please use `auth` retrieved from your script. If you want to see the script for authorizing for Node.js, you can see Quickstart for Node.js. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/slides/quickstart/nodejs) In this case, please use the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations`.

```
const presentationId = "###"; // Please set the presentation ID (Google Slides ID).
const pageNumber = 5; // Please set the page number. In your question, it's 5.
const numberOfCopy = 3; // Please set the number of copy. In your question, it's 3.

const slides = google.slides({ version: "v1", auth: auth });
slides.presentations.get(
  {
    presentationId: presentationId,
    fields: "slides(objectId)",
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    const pageObjectId = res.data.slides[pageNumber - 1].objectId;
    const requests = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfCopy; i++) {
      requests.push({ duplicateObject: { objectId: pageObjectId } });
    }
    slides.presentations.batchUpdate(
      {
        presentationId: presentationId,
        resource: { requests: requests },
      },
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log(res.data);
      }
    );
  }
);
```

- When above script is run, the page object ID of No. 5 slide is retrieved from the Google Slides using the get method, and create the request body for copying 3 times and request it using the batchUpdate method.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, it supposes that `auth` retrieved from your authorization script can be used. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Method: presentations.get](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/get)
- [Method: presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)
- [DuplicateObjectRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#duplicateobjectrequest)

Comment: @developer55555 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.